# Can't reference column by using predefined parameter as part of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where I would like to reference my column by using predefined parameter as a part of the string. The reason for this is that the columns I want to keep will change depending on the time of the year and the year.

My parameter are:

```
year = '20'
```

This is working fine and give me the desired result:

```
df.['Q1 FY20'] = df.['Q1 FY20'].astype('int32')
```

But when I try to replace the "20" in my string with my parameter, I get KeyError: 'Q1 FY20':

```
df.['Q1 FY' + year] = df.['Q1 FY' + year].astype('int32')
```

I dont really get this as I have checked that:

```
type('Q1 FY20') == type('Q1 FY' + year)
'Q1 FY20' == 'Q1 FY' + year
```

... and they are both true. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete error message:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Q1 FY20'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-474-3a24ee57971a> in <module>
----> 1 df['Q1 FY' + year] = df['Q1 FY' + year].astype('int32')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Q1 FY20'
```
````

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data?

Comment: I just updated the post with the complete error message. For the sample, would you like something in the format as df.head()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
year = '20'
column_name = "Q1 FY" + year

df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype('int32')
```

Snapshot:
[image: Result]

Comment: I get the same KeyError with this solution.

Comment: Please check whether the column names are correct in pandas dataframe !

Comment: When i write out the full string like: 'Q1 FY20' it gives me the desired result. Is there anything else that I should check?

Comment: I have added a snapshot displaying result

Comment: Hope the issue is resolved . If yes, Please consider voting up and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the my mistake, I was trying to test the code in an instance before I did the required cleaning of the data.

When I replaced the actual code with my parameter it worked. I do however still not understand why I didn't get any KeyError when I was writing out the full string.

Thanks a lot everybody!